# How to use Axios and React Router to get data from API in a new Route, without using query parameters

Tags: javascript, reactjs, url, axios, react-router-dom

I'm trying to a given url to open a modal with the information about a car. The user can do it from selecting the car from the table, but I want to be able to past a link in the searchBar of the browser or if I sent you the link, to open the modal with the details of the selected car.

The normal flow is the user selecting is to click on a car that is displayed in a table and opening a modal with the selected car details, having the table in the background.

I can't provide any pictures of this, sorry.

The path I have for the route is `/cars/:companyId/:storageId/:carId` being the `/cars` path, the route to display the table.

What happens is, set this url in the browser `http://www.companyX:8080/cars/TC23SD/DMLSN1/FS-1452`, and I make the api call with this Url `companies/TC23SD/storages/DMLSN1` the request url that Axios uses is `http://www.companyX.com:8080/cars/TC23SD/DMLSN1/companies/TC23SD/storages/DMLSN1` and I get an 404 error and it's correct, because the correct request url should be `http://www.companyX.com:8080.com/companies/TC23SD/storages/DMLSN1`.

My objective is to use the am URL (you set on the browser) without query parameters.

Is this possible?

Sorry for the long post here, I tried to explain my self the better I could.

Comment: Can you not construct the correct API URL from the route parameters?

Comment: I pass to axios the url /companies/TC23SD/storages/DMLSN1. The other part is created dinamically and it depends of the company that is login in the app